# how to upgrade from Ubuntu 8.04 LTS to the latest more compatible version

Tags: upgrade, 8.04

I am not very knowledgable on Ubuntu in general but for the past few days I have been getting a bit of knowlege here and there. At first this desktop was only set to turn on and run in ¨Terminal"mode like cmd black and white, but since this computer runs and comunnicates with our other software found in different computers we needed to have a GUI which after some research I was able to installand now I find out it is called Gnome.

Anywho, while I was exited that I was able to get it this far found out that this is running an old version Ubuntu 8.04 LTS Hardy Heron. It is prompting me to do tons of updates and suggesting to upgrade to 10.04.3 LTS I wouldnt mind to do so but would the upgrade damage or delete the files and software it has to communicate with our other software/servers? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to decide whether having a stable platform that you wont need to update for a long time is more important to you or having the latest features.

If you decide on Long term stability you will want the latest LTS release; which at the time of writing is 12.04.  If you want the latest features its currently 13.04.

As 8.04 is really old and no longer supported I would strongly recommend you do a clean install.  You will get a much cleaner system.

Backup your personal data on at least two external devices: External USB drives, DVDs, etc.

Install a supported release letting it overwrite the existing version.  Finally restore your personal data from the backup.

Note: computers don't screw up often but when they do its easy to lose a lot of irreplaceable information so if your data is important to you keep it backed up.

Personally I have all my home computers backed up and stored in the company fire safe.  My company computers are backed up and stored in a fire safe at my home.  I would have to be very unlucky for the house and office to burn down on the same day.